# Scrambling a web page by using XPath

Tags: json, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using XPath syntax and Scampy to scramp a web page with the following structure

```
<ul id="brandList">

        <li class="no-mrg">
            <a href="link">
                <span class="single-logo"><img src="image.png"/></span>
                <span class="single-brand">BRAND1</span>
            </a>
         </li>

        <li class="no-mrg">
            <a href="link2">
                <span class="single-logo"><img src="image2.png"/></span>
                <span class="single-brand">BRAND2</span>
            </a>
         </li>

        ...
```

I'm using scrampy but since I'm new and I don't understand where I'm wrong. I don't get the expected result

here is the code

```
def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//li[@class='no-mrg']"):
            brand = BrandItem()
            brand['brand'] = sel.xpath("span[@class='single-brand']/text()").extract()
            brand['logo'] = sel.xpath("img/@src").extract()
            yield brand
```

I use this function to get a json object but I don't get the object expected.
I would get a json object having the following structure:

```
[
{brand: 'brand1', logo: 'logo'},
]
```

I'm pretty sure I wrong the XPath syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output the items as a json, use `scrapy crawl spider -t json -o filename.json`.

Also your xpaths should be like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in Selector(response).xpath("//li[@class='no-mrg']/a"):
        brand = BrandItem()
        brand['brand'] = sel.xpath("span[@class='single-brand']/text()").extract()
        brand['logo'] = sel.xpath("span[@class='single-logo']/img/@src").extract()
        yield brand
```